# Savings on tax money as a married person?

Tags: salary, united-kingdom, taxes

As I am on normal wage in which I don't have any saving and it's my first job in UK, and as a foreigner I don't know much about rules. I heard somewhere that I can talk to my HR manager to cut me back on tax that I pay, as I am married and married people have to pay less then single? What are other ways I save do saving best and not pay something which I don't know of?

Comment: "Cut me back" ? HR don't control what tax you pay you need to check with HRMC to see if you are on the right code - Married tax allowance is only worth about 200 £ a year

Comment: And anything that you "save" this year you will end paying it when taxes are due. The porcentaje that your employer pays directly to the state is based on an estimation of the result of your next tax declaration; if you reduce it too much you will have to pay the difference next year.

Comment: Also, for your reference: https://www.gov.uk/married-couples-allowance/what-youll-get

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "save do saving best"? Are you specifically looking for other ways to save tax?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam my English isn't that good. I mean, best way to save.

Answer (score 3):

As you're working, you and your spouse were probably born after 1935, so I'll assume that [Marriage Allowance](https://www.gov.uk/marriage-allowance-guide/overview) is relevant to you rather than [Married Couple's Allowance](https://www.gov.uk/married-couples-allowance/overview).

The allowance applies if your husband or wife earns less than the personal allowance in salary (£10,600/year), and less than £5,000/year in savings interest. For example it's likely this will apply if he or she's not working. Also, you need to be only a basic rate taxpayer, earning less than £42,385/year.

In that case they can [register online](https://www.gov.uk/marriage-allowance) to transfer £1,060 of their personal allowance to you, which will reduce your tax bill by £212/year if you yourself earn more than £1,060 above the personal allowance.

This will usually work by [HMRC issuing a new tax code to your employer](https://www.gov.uk/marriage-allowance-guide/how-it-works) who will then automatically withhold less of your salary. You can't get your employer to do this directly, you have to go via HMRC.

The allowance change will be effective as if from the start of the curren tax year in April 2015, so you will probably end up getting the proportion of the £212 that you could have had up till now (from April to August) back all at once in your next pay cheque, or possibly spread out over the rest of the tax year. Apart from that you'll get it spread out evenly over the year - i.e. about £17/month.